# Create database schema and eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a doubt about eloquent, it should be a very basic doubt but Im not understanding.

For example, if we build a db diagram in mysql workbench or something like that, then if we want to create the same shema in laravel we need to add in the migrations the necessary id´s right?

The eloquent relationships (hasMany, belongsTo, etc) are just methods to fetch the info that is necessary in some context but the database schema, the relationships are set with the ids in the migrations right? The relationships (hasMany, belongsTo, etc) are not mandatory to build the database schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migration would define the foreign keys that form the relationships described by hasMany, belongsTo, etc.

A seeder would need to do as you suggest and get the id for the row in the associated table so it can be populated in the foreign key column.

You can, of course, do some seeding in your migrations, but that should be done under very clear and limited circumstance.